# How does Opensea mobile app manage "Log in with metamask / trust / rainbow"?

Tags: wallets, signature, proof-of-authority, authentication

So I was playing around with opensea today and noticed a login feature that uses crypto wallets. I am curious to understand how they achieved it in a native app.

The flow is something like this

1. User clicks "Log in with metamask" button
2. App directs users to metamask wallet on their phone (I assume with some deep linking)
3. Metamask app displays view asking user to sign a message
4. User signs a message and is then informed that they can return back to the opensea app
5. Returning back to opensea app now has user authenticated

Really curious to understand how this works especially the last step i.e. how is opensea informed about correct signing?

Comment: Any updates? Did you figure it out? I'm trying to do the same, but without success yet.

Comment: You have to implement the concept of the DAPP Browser. Just search for it. It will help you.@FedericoMadoery @llja

Answer (score 0):

This is actually done with metamask Deep link to connect your DApp to metamask
`https://metamask.app.link/dapp/[Your DApp url]`